# Reading in a single polygon from a shapefile

Tags: shapefile, r, gml, rgdal

I have a shapefile/GML file with many thousands of polygons insides a specific layer.

I know the set of IDs that reference the set of polygons that I want to get the coordinates data from. Is there a way to get **just this information** easily, **without having to load the whole shapefile** layer into memory first?

I am currently using R with the rgdal package to load the shapefile/GML file, but am happy to look into other tools that might be able to help.

Comment: Can you just subset the layer first? For example go into QGIS and select just the ids that you want and export a new version?

Comment: I don't know if it's possible to read just one polygon from a Shapefile. However, I'd suggest you to have a look at the `sf` package, which at least will grant you a great improvement in reading speed.

Comment: This can be done using OGRSQL on FID in recent versions of GDAL. It's long been possible, just not efficient until recently.  You need to craft a VRT and R can read that.     I'm also working on this kind of flexibility via Rcpp/GDAL here: https://github.com/hypertidy/vapour  I'd be happy to target a very specific application if you are interested.

Answer (score 8):

Time to ditch the shapefile!
Here's a reproducible example using a combination of packages sf, gdalUtils and dplyr:

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(mapview)
library(gdalUtils)

## as an example we take nc shapefile from package sf
shpfile = system.file("shape/nc.shp", package = "sf")

## set working directory (where to save the converted file)
setwd("test_folder")

## covert to gpkg
target_file = gsub(".shp", ".gpkg", basename(shpfile))
ogr2ogr(src_datasource_name = shpfile, 
        dst_datasource_name = target_file, 
        f = "GPKG")

## use dplyr to connect to gpkg file
conn = target_file
db = src_sqlite(conn)

## read fid 10 from gpkg file
pol = tbl(db, "nc") %>% 
  filter(fid == 10) %>% 
  collect %>% 
  st_sf(crs = 4267)

## view with mapview
mapview(pol)

## check with original
mapview(read_sf(shpfile), col.regions = "grey") + pol
```

This is possible because `gpkg` is essentially a self-contained database. Therefore we can read using dplyr database functionality and hence filter by `fid` before `collect`ing the data into memory. Afterwards we convert to a spatial object (`sf` in this case).